# selection validation of Devexpress gridview from client side

Tags: devexpress

I have got a devexpress gridview with Selection Enabled.

Is it possible that, on a Button click to check whether rows are selected or not from **clientside.**

If not prpmpt alert saying--> 'NO ROW IS SELECTED'

Basically i need to loop through gridview from **client side** and check if selected or not.

Can this be done. If so please help me out.

Comment: Yea it can Devexpress actually has ClientSideEvent between it's properties you should be able to use those to achieve your goal. Maybe SelectionChanged would be a good one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.  You should call the GridView's client side [GetSelectedRowCount()](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewScriptsASPxClientGridView_GetSelectedRowCounttopic) method to determine the number of rows selected in the ASPxGridView.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool value = Convert.ToBoolean(gvMain.SelectedRowsCount);
```